# How to execute call back function after POST, PUT, DELETE success by using redux-observable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-observable

I am using the below code for GET, POST, PUT, DELETE calls and it works properly for GET, but unable to get into the success(mergeMap) block for POST, PUT, DELETE, don't know what mistake I am doing, it should enter, I am not getting any response apart from status of 200

Code:

```
const testEpic: Epic<Action, ReduxState> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<any>,
  store: MiddlewareAPI<any, ReduxState>,
) =>
  action$
    .ofType(TEST_GET)
    .mergeMap((action) => {
      return Observable.merge(
          .getJSON('/path/test')
          .mergeMap((response) => {
             // calls not coming here for POST, PUT, DELETE even though it is status 200
          })
      )
    }
    )
    .catch((error) => {

    })
```

Actuually using the below code for getJSON

```
Observable<any> => {
    return Observable.fromPromise(.fetch(url, options))
  }
```

Comment: `return Observable.merge(
          .getJSON('/path/test')` You're using `.getJSON` with nothing before the dot, that could be an issue?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer I am using .fetch for all api calls

Comment: @SaikatSaha I think Dane meant `.getJSON` versus `getJSON` or `x.getJSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, the response was going inside error because of wrong contentType